# Is there a way to remsh it which I choose part?

Tags: sculpt, remesh

as you can see, i want to remesh i want section without losing another part details, but I couldn't. even I've tried slice and rejoin using mask tool but failed. How should I do? Is there a way to remsh it which i choose part? oh...damn i'm stucking in this problem for many weeks. Please Show me the way.

[image]

Comment: Enable Dyntopo instead of remesh. But this will triangulate your mesh.

Comment: ㄴThanks for comment!